# I need to filter my data and create a subset from a dataframe based on a range values of latitude and longitude

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have the following data (in a bigger extent):

How will I be able to filter my data based on a range of latitude, longitude simultaneusly say for lati >= 52.46 and <= 52.50 and for longitude >= -1.87 and <= -1.92

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what software you are asking about?

Comment: I am sorry in R

Comment: Please take a look a the R documentation : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/438/data-frames/2047/subsetting-rows-and-columns-from-a-data-frame#t=201612041001004962743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work.

If you get the error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` that's because you need to rename your latitude column.

```
#create a reproducible data.frame
df = read.table(text ='ID    Lat    Long
1     124   76
2     234   53
3     229   11
4     268   22
5     150   44
6     190   34
7     211   87  
8     152   21
9     300   98
10    186   19', header = TRUE)

#subset the data.frame
df_sub = subset(df, Lat >= 150 & Lat <= 299 & Long >= 22 & Long <= 97)

#output
> df_sub
ID Lat Long
2  2 234   53
4  4 268   22
5  5 150   44
6  6 190   34
7  7 211   87
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create another column with a boolean value, setting it to 1 if the corresponding row passed the condition or 0 if it didn't.

then use the VLOOKUP function to filter only those rows wich passed the condition (having the new column value = 1)

Comment: I need to do it in R otherwise in excel it will take like ages

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you stored your data in a data frame df, and range 1 through 4 are your latitude and longitude limits-

```
df_sub <- df[df$latitude >= range1 & df$latitude <= range2 &
             df$longitude >= range3 & df$longitude <= range4,]
```

Comment: Sorry about that but I am new in R so please be patient. It gives me this error: Error in df$latitude : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable